# How to extract lower and upper bounds from confidence level in R from t test function?

Tags: r, statistics, confidence-interval, t-test

I used the following code to retrieve a confidence level for my data:

```
out <- t.test(my_data$my_col, conf.level = 0.95)
out
```

This returns something like:

```
data:  my_data$my_column
t = 30, df = 20, p-value < 2.1e-14
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 62.23191 80.11201
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 75.10457
```

I've tried doing:

```
out[4][1]
```

But this returns:

```
$conf.int
[1]  62.23191 80.11201
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

How do I specifically get the lower bound and upper bound from this respectively? (i.e. how do I extract 62.23191 and 80.11201 as variables?)

Comment: As frustrating as it is for a beginner I highly recommend looking up the difference between single bracket indexing and double bracket indexing. You almost had it but one of those needed to be a double bracket index instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `t.test()` is a list.  The confidence interval is stored as a vector within the $conf.int list element.

To access the individual confidence intervals use `out$conf.int[1]` & `out$conf.int[2]`

Example:

```
out <- t.test(1:10, y=c(7:20)) 
out$conf.int
#[1] -11.052802  -4.947198
#attr(,"conf.level")
#[1] 0.95
out$conf.int[1]
#[1] -11.0528
out$conf.int[2]
#[1] -4.947198
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `broom` package not sure if it is more efficient than  accepted answer but it is another option.

```
library(broom)

tidy(t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20),conf.int = TRUE)

 estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic   p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method                  alternative
     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                   <chr>      
1       -8       5.5      13.5     -5.43 0.0000186      22.0    -11.1     -4.95 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided
```